# How can I import a .scss module within my main.scss with @use

Tags: css, sass

So, let's assume I have the following situation: I have 2 .scss files. 
One with a variable, and one that will be actually translated into .css for my webpage, where I want to access to said variable.

**vars.scss**

```
$my_color: red;
```

**main.scss**

```
@use 'vars'

body {
  color: $my_color;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to access the variable defined in `vars.css` and use it. 
The reference is correct since if I use `@import` instead of `@use`, everything works
I've also tried to reference to the variable with `vars.$my_color` as was suggested in the documentation, but I keep getting a "*undefined variable*" error.

Comment: Hmm, I don't use "use". I just have one main scss where I "import" all the other files. my vars is the first i import. This should not give a problem to use your variables everywhere with this method. EDIT: "The reference is correct since if I use import instead of @use, everything works." Why don't import?

Comment: Mostly because the SASS documentation states that 'import' will be deprecated soon and suggests to use 'use' instead. But yeah, I'll just 'import' if I fail to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you read the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) then in the `⚠️ Heads up!` section, where the undesirability of further use of the @import rule is written, below, you can read the following:

---

The @import rule has a number of serious problems:

@import makes all variables, mixins, and functions globally available.

---

Therefore, the **@use** rule makes them **inaccessible**. Which is what you observe in action.

I think to achieve the desired result, combination of @use and @forward rules should be used.

But I am using VSCode Live Sass Compiler (Maybe you're using it too?) where [@use is not supported](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/251) so I couldn't give you the exact howto.

Hope this clarifies a lot.

Comment: Yes I'm using VSCode with Live Sass Compiler, too.

Thank you, anyway. I'll stick to import for now :)